# Joining or merging two dictionaries where same key produces unioned value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, enums

I'm using the answer from this link [Linq join two dictionaries using a common key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057178/linq-join-two-dictionaries-using-a-common-key)

to produce the result that I want.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to convert the result back into a dictionary object, since the result is some type of System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator and I'm not sure what to do with that.

Okay, specifics.
Suppose I have the following:

```
[Flags]
enum People { Adam = 0x1, Barry = 0x2, Chris = 0x4, David = 0x8, 
            Eric = 0x10, Frank = 0x20, George = 0x40, Harold = 0x80 };

Dictionary<string, People> EUInterest = new Dictionary<string, People>() { 
    { "athletes", People.Adam | People.Barry }, 
    { "artists", People.Frank | People.Harold } };

Dictionary<string, People> USInterest = new Dictionary<string, People>() { 
    { "athletes", People.Chris | People.Harold }, 
    { "artists", People.Eric } };

var result = from interest in EUInterest.Keys
             where USInterest.ContainsKey(interest)
             let v1 = EUInterest[interest]
             let v2 = USInterest[interest]
             select new Dictionary<string, People>() { {interest, v1 | v2 } };
```

When I look at result in the debugger, I see the "Results View" has almost what I want it to have. It looks like it creates two dictionaries with a single Key.  Which, now that I look closely at the query, that's exactly what it does.

Here is what I want the result to be:

```
Dictionary<string, People> result =  new Dictionary<string, People>() { 
    { "athletes", People.Adam | People.Barry | People.Chris | People.Harold }, 
    { "artists", People.Frank | People.Harold | People.Eric } };
```

Even if I'm able to get the `var result` how I want it from the select query, I'm not sure how to access that data, because it won't be a Dictionary object.  (I can easily use the wonderful merge extension that Andrew Orsich provided here: [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp))

Comment: You could convert into a `HashSet` then use a Union to merge the values then keep the same key.

Comment: Why not use dictionary<string, List<People>> ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert it into HashSet, but I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this after your result?

```
        var finalDic = new Dictionary<string, People>();

        foreach (var dic in result) {
            foreach (var key in dic.Keys) {
                People people;
                if (finalDic.TryGetValue(key, out people)) {
                    finalDic[key] = people | dic[key];  
                }
                else {
                    finalDic[key] = dic[key];
                }                   
            }
        }
```

//Output

athletes: Adam, Barry, Chris, Harold

artists: Eric, Frank, Harold

But you can simple take you first dictionary as a initial object and use the second to do something similar as i dit above:

```
        var EUxUSInterest = new Dictionary<string, People>(EUInterest);

        foreach (var element in USInterest) {
            People people;
            if (EUxUSInterest.TryGetValue(element.Key, out people)) {
                EUxUSInterest[element.Key] = people | element.Value;    
            }
            else {
                EUxUSInterest[element.Key] = element.Value;
            }   
        }
```

//Output is the same

athletes: Adam, Barry, Chris, Harold

artists: Eric, Frank, Harold

Comment: Yes, I suppose I'm trying to make it more difficult than it needs to be. My only question is would this iteration be costly based on how many false iterations it creates.

Comment: Yes, I am making it more difficult than it needs to be since my solution below essentially throws in a middle set of steps to do exactly what your solution does in the first place.

Comment: i see, i just got you final object but i believe you can improve by doing something similar before your original result query, see the update

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the most efficient way to do it (I'll look into the HashSet idea). The answer on my question about the query is that I should use it in the foreach loop raw.  I was trying to use the query by accessing some property.

This answer uses the MergeLeft Dictionary extension mentioned in the question above.

```
[Flags]
enum People
{
    None = 0x0, Adam = 0x1, Barry = 0x2, Chris = 0x4, David = 0x8, 
    Eric = 0x10, Frank = 0x20, George = 0x40, Harold = 0x80, Ian = 0x100, 
    Joe = 0x200, Larry = 0x400, Mark = 0x800, Nathan = 0x1000, Oscar = 0x2000, 
    Paul = 0x4000, Roger = 0x8000, Sam = 0x10000, Tom = 0x20000, 
    Victor = 0x40000, Walter = 0x80000,Yogi = 0x100000, Zane = 0x200000
};

Dictionary<string, People> EUInterest = new Dictionary<string, People>() { 
{ "athletes", People.Adam | People.Barry }, 
{ "artists", People.Frank | People.Harold } };
Dictionary<string, People> USInterest = new Dictionary<string, People>() { 
{ "athletes", People.Chris | People.Harold }, 
{ "artists", People.Eric } };

var query = from interest in EUInterest.Keys
                where USInterest.ContainsKey(interest)
                let v1 = EUInterest[interest]
                let v2 = USInterest[interest]
                select new Dictionary<string, People>() { {interest, v1 | v2 } };

Dictionary<string, People> temp = new Dictionary<string, People>();
foreach (var a in query)
{
    temp = temp.MergeLeft(a);
}

foreach (People option in Enum.GetValues(typeof(People)))
{
    if (temp["athletes"].HasFlag(option))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} IS AN ATHLETE.", option);
    // else Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an athlete.", option);
}
```